# Trying to write a java program that takes 2 text files and merges them into one; cannot make it past this one error message

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
 public class FrankenNovel
    {


        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            //Book 1
            File bookFile1 = new File("LittleWomen.txt");
            Book book1 = new Book(bookFile1);
            System.out.println("Book 1: Little Women by Louisa May Alcott");
            System.out.println("Word count: " + book1.getWordCount());
            System.out.println("Longest word: " + book1.getLongestWord() + "\n");
              //ERROR OCCURS on book1.getWordCount and .getLongestWord//  
            //Book 2
            File bookFile2 = new File("TheWizardofOz.txt");
            Book book2 = new Book(bookFile2);
            System.out.println("Book 2: The Wonderful Wizard of Oz by L. Frank Baum");
            System.out.println("Word count: " + book2.getWordCount());
            System.out.println("Longest word: " + book2.getLongestWord() + "\n");**
```

//ERROR OCCURS on book2.getWordCount and .getLongestWord;

Error is

> method getLongestWord in class Book cannot be applied to given types
>   required: java.lang.string; found: no arguments; reason: actual and
>   formal arguments differ in length

```
//FrankenNovel
            writeFrankenNovel(book1, book2);        
            System.out.println("My FrankenNovel, The Wizarding Women, has been created in frankenOutput.txt.");
        }
class Book
{
    //// FIELDS ////
    private String longestWord;
    private int wordCount;
    private ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
    /* Declare fields for the word list, the word count, and the longest word.*/

    ////// CONSTRUCTOR //////
    //@param f -- the file object
    public Book(File f)
    {
        wordList = readBook(f);
        wordCount = countWords(wordList);
        longestWord = findLongestWord(wordList);
```

Comment: When asking for assistance, it is important to include the _actual_ error that occurs. With that said, there is no method `getLongestWord()` or `getWordCount()` shown in the code here.

Comment: What does this Book class has to do with merging files? You don't need it at all, it's completely irrelevant to the task. Have a separate piece of code for merging files than the one that does this word counting and finding of longest words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have quoted tells us that `getLongestWord` expects a `String` as parameter, but you are not passing one to it. Take a look at these lines:

```
        System.out.println("Word count: " + book1.getWordCount());
        System.out.println("Longest word: " + book1.getLongestWord() + "\n");
```

Here `book1.getLongestWord()` will fail, `book1.getLongestWord("Some thing")` would run. However, it seems that these methods were not defined properly. Let's define `getLongestWord` properly:

```
public String getLongestWord() {
    String longestWord = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
        if (wordList.get(i).size() > longestWord) longestWord = wordList.get(i);
    }
}
```

and let's define `wordCount` as well:

```
public int wordCount() {
    return wordList.size();
}
```